# change content infowindow maps v3

Tags: javascript, maps, infowindow

I am trying to make it possible to change the content that shows up inside a DIV that is the content of an infowindow. I have been able to change the content from Hello to YO inside the infowindow. The problem is when I close the infowindow and reopen it the updated content reverts back to the original. Below is my code:

```js
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
      if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
          //event.overlay.setTitle("Hello");
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: '<div id="content" onmouseover="updateContent()">Hello</div>',
              maxWidth: 10
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map, event.overlay);
          });
      }
  });

  function updateContent() {
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "Yo";
  }
```

I basically want to create a default info window and allow the user to input their own text after they place the marke on the page...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have to set the content through setContentHTML method

```
var infowindow ;
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        //event.overlay.setTitle("Hello");
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div id="content" onmouseover="updateContent()">Hello</div>',
            maxWidth: 10
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay,'click',function()
        infowindow.open(map,event.overlay);
     });
}});

function updateContent(){
    infowindow.setContent("YO");
}
```

Comment: When I've tried this I get an error that setContentHTML is not a method of Google's infoWindow object (I believe it's standard DHTML but Google's infoWindow object doesn;t inherit it). To achieve the OP's objective I detached the existing infoWindow, created a new infoWindow object with the new content then attached that to the existing marker.

Comment: You can use "infowindow.setContent(...)" function instead, which works nice for me :)

Comment: Nice identation

Comment: Won't this create an info window for every overlay that is created? Couldn't you just create one info window and update as needed?

Answer (score 14):

I found the above accepted answer didn't work as I had to use setContent() as follows:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {
    if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        //event.overlay.setTitle("Hello");
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div id="content" onmouseover="updateContent()">Hello</div>',
            maxWidth: 10
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, event.overlay);
        });
    }
});
function updateContent() {
    infowindow.setContent("Yo");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best is to create the content of the InfoWindow not by using a HTML string, but with a DOM Element.
So replace:

```
new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<div id="content" onmouseover="updateContent()">Hello</div>'
    });
```

with:

```
var domElement = document.createElement('div');
domElement.innerHTML = '<div id="content" onmouseover="updateContent()">Hello</div>';
new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: domElement
    });
```

Now you can easily access the div with `document.getElementById("content");` and do all the DOM manipulation you want.

Comment: This deserves a medal. Seriously easy solution to a problem. This solved an issue I would have spent enormous time on in two lines of code. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work `document.getElementById("content");` returns null for me. I had to add `document.body.appendChild(domElement);` after `domElement.innerHTML = ...` to make it work