# allowing user to add info windows on google maps after adding a makrer on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am a very new person to the google maps and javascript. What i am trying to achieve is that when i load a google map the user should be able to add a marker/pin on any location he wishes via click. I am able to do this now what i am trying to add is that if a user clicks the pin gets added there should also be a description window which user could add on that pin. Say when i click on a location to add a pin i should also be able to insert some description like "my home" etc.Below is my code so far. Thanks anyways.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Accessing arguments in UI events</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });
}

function placeMarker(position, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map
  });
  map.panTo(position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add on click listener to your marker to open an info window when you click on your marker.
Create your infowindow after where you created your marker:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content : 'Test Content'
});
```

and after that, add the listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, "click", function() {
   infowindow.open( map, marker );
});
```

Comment: HI
First thanks for the comment. However due to my limited knowledge i am not able to get it to work so what i tried from your answer is that i created my infowindow after my marker in my function placemarker(). Kindly have a look at the code below. It does nothing when i insert a pin.Basically i edited this in my existing code
function placeMarker(position, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map
  });
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content : 'Test Content'
});
  map.panTo(position);
}

Comment: Did you add the listener? Just write `google.maps...` as I wrote above after `map.panTo(position);` and it should work.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot really It is perfect It was my bad i was adding this line outside my placemarker function.
One last thing it appears 'test content' when you click now is there a way that user can add this content when he clicks on the marker in other words a blank info window opens and user should write words?
Thanks anyways

Comment: @Loraloper yes you can, you should define content string with html tags and with an input e.g. `"<input type='text'>"` insted of `'Test Content'`. It is all upto you, think that infowindow as a small html page :)

Comment: Yes that works to some extent but when i close that field and click on that marker again everything user has entered gets lost. Again my poor knowledge of javascript in general. Thanks

Comment: I think this is a more advanced question, but it is sure possible, you need another event which catches key press events on your textbox and updates your infowindow content upon you entered something. It is best to open a new question but first take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289214/change-content-infowindow-maps-v3 and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: I juts could not stop thanking you. yes let me ask a new question i tried to understand from your links but i am a person with limited abilities